# error messages: 0 and warning messages: 1

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, sybase

I'm migrating a VC++ code from VS2008 to VS2013. It connects to sybase database. I get this error "error message: 0" and warning "warning message: 1", its so weird, unfortunately clicking on this error also does not take to the error code.

Please find the output below:

```
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project:Tools, Configuration: Release MinDependency Win32 ------
3>  Performing registration
3>  M_WHEN_WARN,Unable to find the SQL statement 'WHENEVER WARNING'.
3>  0 Error(s) and 1 Warning(s) found.
3>  Statistical Report:
3>      Program name: cpre 
3>      Options specified: /m /r  
3>      Input file name: sqlbox.cp 
3>      Listing file name:  
3>      Target file name: sqlbox.cpp 
3>      ISQL file name:  
3>      Tag ID specified:  
3>      Compiler used: ANSI_C 
3>      Open Client version: CS_VERSION_150 
3>      Number of information messages: 11 
**3>CUSTOMBUILD : Number of warning messages: 1**
**3>CUSTOMBUILD : Number of error messages: 0**
3>      Number of SQL statements parsed: 34 
3>      Number of host variables declared: 43 
3>      Number of SQL cursors declared: 1 
3>      Number of dynamic SQL statements: 0 
3>      Number of stored Procedures generated: 2 
3>      Connection(s) information:
3>          User id: yyyyy
3>          Server: xxxxxx 
3>          Database: zzzz
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any help to fix this error and warning is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Visual-C++, the warning is generated by a Sybase utility.  Cpre is a pre-compiler that generates source code and .isql files.  It is unhappy about a SQL statement in the sqlbox.cp source code file.  We cannot see it, you need to take a look at it.  Contact Sybase support if you need more help.

Comment: @HansPassant Cpre.exe is not available in sybase 15 version. I read somewhere that it is usually present in Sybase/bin folder. Do you know where to find it?. I have the oldest version of cpre in a custom build program, now I would like to replace the old one with the latest to check whether if it works fine or not. Becuase I believe it to be a compatiblity issue.